# Magento 2 Shipping Methods Are Not Loading in IE 10

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-methods

I got an issue that **shipping methods** are not loading in **checkout** only in **IE 10**, remaining all browsers shipping methods are loading but in only IE 10 Shipping methods are not loading.

But once if I refresh the page then they are loading and these only occur in production mode only but not in developer mode. Can any have face this kind of issue, Please help us. We are using ahead works one page checkout.